# iptables redirect blocked IPs from one chain to a honeypot

Tags: iptables, honeypot

I am currently using psad to automatically block potentially harmful IPs. When it detects an attack it adds the ip to PSAD_BLOCKED_INPUT or PSAD_BLOCK_OUTPUT and then drops all further traffic from this source.

So far so good, but what I want is to redirect the traffic from these blocked IPs to a honeypot running on a VM. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: This is more of a pure routing question than an InfoSec question (despite the use of a honeypot). I'm voting to migrate to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to take a shot at @cybernard answer and, guess what, I did work! Thank you so much :)

So here is how I did it:

## Part 1: Add blocked IPs into an ipset

psad automatically writes every blocked IP into a text file named auto_blocked_ips located in /var/log/psad. So we first need to add it into an ipset which I called banned_nets.

I wrote this simple script to do it dynamically:

```
#!/bin/bash
#ipset banned_nets must already exist

AUTO_BLOCKED_IPTABLES_PATH=/var/log/psad/auto_blocked_iptables

update_set(){
    ipset flush banned_nets

    grep -E -o '^([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}' $AUTO_BLOCKED_IPTABLES_PATH |  while read -r line ; do
         echo "Processing $line"
        ipset add banned_nets $line
    done
 }

while true #run indefinitely 
do
    inotifywait -e modify $AUTO_BLOCKED_IPTABLES_PATH | update_set
done
```

## Part 2: Define forwarding rules

Now we need rules to forward the traffic from the server to the honeypot. The detail is that actually we need two rules, so the server act as a transparent proxy.

Here is how I did it (once more, thanks to @cybernard):

```
###### forwarding ######
ipset create banned_nets hash:ip hashsize 4096

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m set --dport 8181 -j DNAT --to-destination $HONEYPOT_ADDR:443 --match-set banned_nets src
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s $HONEYPOT_ADDR --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source $SERVER_ADDR:8181

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m set -j DNAT --to-destination $HONEYPOT_ADDR --match-set banned_nets src
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -m set -j DNAT --to-destination $HONEYPOT_ADDR --match-set banned_nets src

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m set -j SNAT --to-source $SERVER_ADDR --match-set banned_nets src
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -m set -j SNAT --to-source $SERVER_ADDR --match-set banned_nets src

echo "[+] Activating IP forwarding"
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

These rules make part of my iptables.sh script.

## Part 3: checking the results

So we have an attacker trying to scan 192.168.56.101 and a honeypot in 192.168.56.100.

[Scanning the server before IP is blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSCoC.png)

After the blocking the attacker actually scans the honeypot

[Scanning the server after IP is blocked (and forwarded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR1rG.png)

Comment: Btw, I created a repo at GitHub with a function project for this: https://github.com/marcosValle/pfcIME/

Comment: Just so you know **ipset save >all.txt** or **ipset save -f /src/all.txt** can be used to save the whole list at once and you can substitute **restore** for **save** when you want to load the whole list in all at once instead of grepping a file manually.

Comment: Also if you need to handle  /var/log/psad.  You can also do **cat  /var/log/psad |cut -f 1|xargs -n1 ipset add banned_nets** Obviously you need to modify the cut part.

Answer (score 0):

First you would have to load /etc/host.deny into an ipset.
Then define a rule to forward it.
iptables -A PREROUTING -m set -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1  --match-set banned_nets src

192.168.1.1 would be where you put your VM ip.

Now it could get tricky as psad may clear all iptables rules and then you would have to add it after psad is initialize.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I made a complete answer of my solution, based in what you said :)